# Managing the palette indicators in gnuplot

Tags: colors, gnuplot

I would like to ask if someone knows how to manage the palette indicators in gnuplot, I want it to fit with my colors(12) and not to be added automatically

my code is

```
 set palette model HSV 
 set palette rgb 3,2,2 
 set palette maxcolors 12 
 set view map
 set size square
 set key off
 set title "Neural network output (fitted curve)"
 set xlabel "x"
 set ylabel "y"
 set zlabel "z"
 set xrange [  -7.6625930750000002  :   27.166801390000000      ]
 set yrange [  0.35422432799999998  :   30.163194489999999      ]
 set zrange [  -55.934824620000001  :   2.4059901000000002E-002 ]
 set grid
 set terminal png size 1200,900
 set output "output/fitted_curve.png "
 splot "output/plot_data_pl.txt " with points palette pt 7 ps 1
```

[image: gnuplot output image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the maximum flexibility, you should define your own `palette`.
Here is what I once did to obtain a plot with 7 distinct colors. Thereby, I can also define which color represents a given range of values.

```
set palette defined (0 "black",\
                     0.5 "black",\
                     0.5 "red",\
                     1.5 "red",\
                     1.5 "orange-red",\
                     2.5 "orange-red",\
                     2.5 "orange",\
                     3.5 "orange",\
                     3.5 "yellow",\
                     4.5 "yellow",\
                     4.5 "light-green",\
                     5.5 "light-green",\
                     5.5 "green",\
                     6.5 "green")
```

[image]

Hence, you actually have to define from / to which value you want a color to span.
Of course, you can use rgb definitions for your color. A list of gnuplot-defined colors is [here](http://www.ss.scphys.kyoto-u.ac.jp/person/yonezawa/contents/program/gnuplot/img/colorname-list.png).

For the sake of completeness, here is the entire code I used:

```
set view map
set pm3d

set term pngcairo crop font 'lmroman10,32' size 1152,864
set border lw 2
set palette defined (0 "black", 0.5 "black", 0.5001 "red", 1.5 "red", 1.5001 "orange-red", 2.5 "orange-red", 2.5001 "orange", 3.5 "orange", 3.5001 "yellow", 4.5 "yellow", 4.5001 "light-green", 5.5 "light-green", 5.5001 "green", 6.5 "green")
set xlab 'time step ' offset 0,1
set xtics 2500 offset 0,0.65
set ylab 'position [cell]' offset +.5,0
set cblab 'velocity [cells/(time step)]' offset -.8,0
set cbtics offset -1.2,0
set xrange[100000:110000]
set yrange[0:10000]
set cbrange[0:6.5]

set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb "blue" lw .85 pt 6 ps .6

splot '6.csv' u (($1)):($2):($3) w p palette t '', 'data.csv' u (($1)):($2):($3*0) w l ls 1 t '',  'data2.csv' u (($1)):($2):($3*0) w l ls 1 t ''
```